# Deserializing a string into an xml when a child element name is dynamic

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I've got the following string, representing an xml hierarchy:

```
 "<cookie page=\"1\">
    <pz_requestid last=\"{987A23F4-8582-E711-8114-005056B74623}\" first=\"{9F2E4A8C-EB7D-E711-8116-005056B71CCD}\" />
 </cookie>";
```

and I need to deserialize it into a class.

My problem is that the child element can have different names. E.g., in the above example, its name is "pz_requestid", but it can be something else, like "pz_accountid". What I don't know is how to build the class hierarchy in a way that will enable desrializing it correctly.

Currently, I've created the following class, that only works if the element  name is `pz_requestid`:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class cookie
{
    public entityidfieldid pz_requestid { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public int page { get; set; }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class entityidfieldid 
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string last {get; set;}

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string first { get; set; }
}
```

and the following deserializing code works:

```
string inputString = "<cookie page=\"1\"><pz_requestid last=\"{987A23F4-8582-E711-8114-005056B74623}\" first=\"{9F2E4A8C-EB7D-E711-8116-005056B71CCD}\" /></cookie>";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(cookie));
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString));
cookie mycookie = (cookie)serializer.Deserialize(memStream);
```

What do I need to change to get what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple with xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = 
                "<cookie page=\"1\">" + 
                "<pz_requestid last=\"{987A23F4-8582-E711-8114-005056B74623}\" first=\"{9F2E4A8C-EB7D-E711-8116-005056B71CCD}\" />" +
                "</cookie>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            Entityidfieldid entityidfieldid = doc.Descendants("cookie").Elements().Select(x => new Entityidfieldid() {
                name = x.Name.LocalName,
                last = (string)x.Attribute("last"),
                first = (string)x.Attribute("first")
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    public partial class Entityidfieldid
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string last { get; set; }
        public string first { get; set; }
    }
}
```